# Join line and print in column

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to join line and get my data is in below form

```
CODE> AA
LINE1>ABCD
LINE2>AJDS
LINE3>AJDO
SYMBOL1>Q1
SYMBOL2>Q2
SYMBOL3>Q3
SYMBOL4>Q4
CODE> BB
LINE1>HFIN
LINE2>HPAD
LINE3>HIDF
LINE4>HINA
SYMBOL1>SA
SYMBOL2>SS
CODE> CC
```

and I am trying to get out something line below where code is constant and appears only 1 time, however **LINE** and **SYMBOL** can appear more than once

| CODE | LINE | SYMBOL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | ABCD | Q1 |
| AA | AJDS | Q2 |
| AA | AJDO | Q3 |
| AA |  | Q4 |
| BB | HFIN | SA |
| BB | HPAD | SS |
| BB | HIDF |  |
| BB | HINF |  |

```
grep -e CODE -e LINE -e SYMBOL test.txt 
|awk'NR%4{printf"%s",$1,$2,$3;}4'
CODE>CODE> AA     
LINE1>ABCDLINE1>ABCD     
LINE2>AJDSLINE2>AJDS      
LINE3>AJDO      
SYMBOL1>Q1SYMBOL1>Q1     
SYMBOL2>Q2SYMBOL2>Q2     
SYMBOL3>Q3SYMBOL3>Q3      
SYMBOL4>Q4      
CODE>CODE> BB     
LINE1>HFINLINE1>HFIN
```

I am not an expert tbh
Thanks
Sandy

Comment: The input format is not clear. I edited your question for encapsulating it in **triple backticks** but there might now be superfluous newlines

Comment: Input format corrected

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: To be honest, i tried Grep and awk to do that, but seems like its not enough, i am not an expert and i accept that, but the one i used is pasted above in the question now

Comment: @SandeepKumar It seems like the sample input is already filtered by `grep`; if you're gonna use `awk` in the end then that's a waste, and it might be easier to process the real input directly with `awk`

Comment: Thanks everyone, appreciate your help ! I have learnt something new today,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an `awk` that implements multi-dim arrays, for example GNU `awk`:

```bash
awk -F '> *' -v OFS=',' '
    $1 == "CODE" {
        code = $2
        next
    }
    match($1,/[0-9]+/) {
        key = substr($1,1,RSTART-1)
        idx = substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        val = $2
        records[code][key][idx] = val
        indexes[code][idx]
    }
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
        for (code in records)
            for (idx in indexes[code])
                print code, records[code]["LINE"][idx], records[code]["SYMBOL"][idx]
    }
' input.txt
```

The output will be an **unquoted** CSV:

```bash
$ cat output.csv
AA,ABCD,Q1
AA,AJDS,Q2
AA,AJDO,Q3
AA,,Q4
BB,HFIN,SA
BB,HPAD,SS
BB,HIDF,
BB,HINA,
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ruby to produce a CSV file from that input:

```
ruby -r csv -e '
codes={}
$<.read.scan(/^CODE>[[:space:]]*(.+)\R([\s\S]*?)(?=^CODE|\z)/){|code, st| 
    codes[code]=st.split(/\R/).map{|s| s.split(/\d+>/)}.
        group_by{|sl| sl.shift}.transform_values(&:flatten)
}

headers=codes.map{|k,v| v.keys}.flatten.uniq

tbl=CSV.parse((["CODES"]+headers).join(","), headers: true)
codes.each{|k,v| 
    (0..(v.length)+1).each{|i|
        tmp=[k]
        headers.each{|hk| tmp<<codes[k][hk][i] }
    tbl<<tmp
    }
}
puts tbl
' file
```

Prints:

```
CODES,LINE,SYMBOL
AA,ABCD,Q1
AA,AJDS,Q2
AA,AJDO,Q3
AA,,Q4
BB,HFIN,SA
BB,HPAD,SS
BB,HIDF,
BB,HINA,
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` approach with parallel simple arrays.

```
$: cat tst
awk -F'[> ]*' -v OFS=',' '
  function rpt() { 
    for(i=0;i<(l>s?l:s);i++) print code, line[i], sym[i];
    l=s=0; split("",line); split("",sym)
  }
  /^CODE/   { rpt(); code=$2; }
  /^LINE/   { line[l++]=$2;   }
  /^SYMBOL/ { sym[s++]=$2;    }
  END{ rpt(); } ' file

$: ./tst
AA,ABCD,Q1
AA,AJDS,Q2
AA,AJDO,Q3
AA,,Q4
BB,HFIN,SA
BB,HPAD,SS
BB,HIDF,
BB,HINA,
```